# Url to play rtmpe on videodisplay component using flex3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, rtmp, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to play a video from amazon cloudfront in a videoDisplay component in flex3.
My problem is that the source url is a rtmp with expire, key-pair-id and Signature parameters. I don't know what final url pass to the videoDisplay source.

Something like this `rtmp://server.com/cfx/st/mp4:file` is running. But... what is the url if i have a signature?

The Signature and other parameters are trust. The problem is formatting the url with theirs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

I was usign:

```
videoPlayer.source = "rtmp://aaaaaa.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/mp4:file?Expires=1296735002&Key-Pair-Id=XXXXXXXXXXX&Signature=YYYYYYY"
```

BUUUT...

file needs an extension. In this case file.mp4
Without params you can delete the extension, but not if you add parameteres next the filename

Solution:

```
videoPlayer.source = "rtmp://aaaaaa.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/mp4:file.mp4?Expires=1296735002&Key-Pair-Id=XXXXXXXXXXX&Signature=YYYYYYY"
```